# How to Contract Card Layout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I've a **mainPanel** with VerticalLayout `(org.jdesktop.swingx.VerticalLayout)`. main panel has several sub panels. One of them is a dynamically changing panel according to the user selection. So, I've set it's layout as `CardLayout` which I think is the easiest (maybe best?) way to achieve that.

I'll call that panel **elasticPanel**. As the name says, it should be elastic. Which means, it should be capable of both expanding and contracting. Let's say it behave like this. If the user select `1`, the **elasticPanel** should display one , say, `JComboBox`. If the user select `2` then, two `JComboBox`s...

Ok, it works perfectly up to now. Now the user select `1` again when the `elasticPanel` is showing two `JComboBox`s. What i need to happen now is the `elasticPanel` should display one `JComboBox` with it's normal size. But since the `elasticPanel` is already expanded, what happens is it shows the `JComboBox` stretched to fit it's size. So it gives a weird look.

---

Following screenshots show the problem i'm having with my interface.

Before the selection. `NONE` is selected.

[image]

An element is selected

[image]

`NONE` is selected again

[image]

I need the `elasticPanel` (*Location of Fault*) in the last screenshot to be as in the first screenshot. This is just a simple case. Imagine the look when going back to `NONE` after displaying about 5, 6 sub components.

I've tried the `setSize()` method. It doesn't do anything..So how to fix the issue?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: (don't quite understand the CardLayout part ..) Anyway: a) calling setSize is **always** wrong (that's the task of the LayoutManager and will not have any effect) b) if the size was fine _before_ showing the second line, it should be fine _after_ hiding it again, provided it's parent gets revalidated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell you are referring `CardLayout` to what thingy. Since [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) works in a different way. What you can do is simply place one `JPanel` say **basePanel** having `GridLayout(0, 1)` and place this `JPanel` on top of another `JPanel` say **contentPanel**, and now set this as the content pane for the `JFrame` and calling pack() when you add or remove an element from the view. Here is one example showing you what I mean.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ElasticPanel
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel basePanel;
    /*
     * Array to hold the JComboBox
     * elements.
     */
    private JComboBox[] prodCombo;  
    private JComboBox[] temp;
    /* 
     * Counter to keep track
     * of the number of JComboBox 
     * present.
     */
    private int counter;  
    /*
     * Data for each JComboBox
     */
    private String[] data = {
                                "None",
                                "Sub Category"
                            };

    private ActionListener comboAction =
            new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JComboBox cbox = (JComboBox) ae.getSource();
            String command = (String) ae.getActionCommand();
            int index = Integer.parseInt(command);
            String selection = (String) cbox.getSelectedItem();

            if (selection.equals("None"))
            {
                /*
                 * i = index + 1, because, we want to
                 * remove all JComboBox after this one.
                 */
                for (int i = (index + 1); i < prodCombo.length; i++)
                {
                    temp = new JComboBox[prodCombo.length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < prodCombo.length; j++)
                        temp[j] = prodCombo[j];
                    basePanel.remove(prodCombo[i]); 
                }
                prodCombo = new JComboBox[index + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
                {                   
                    prodCombo[i] = temp[i];
                }
                counter = prodCombo.length;
                System.out.println("Item Removed\nCounter : " + counter);
            }
            else if (selection.equals("Sub Category"))
            {
                counter++;
                temp = new JComboBox[counter];
                for (int i = 0; i < prodCombo.length; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = prodCombo[i];
                }
                temp[counter - 1] = new JComboBox(data);
                temp[counter - 1].setActionCommand("" + (counter - 1));
                temp[counter - 1].addActionListener(this);
                prodCombo = new JComboBox[counter];
                for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    prodCombo[i] = temp[i];
                basePanel.add(prodCombo[counter - 1]);  
                System.out.println("Item Added\nCounter : " + counter);
            }

            //basePanel.revalidate();
            //basePanel.repaint();
            frame.pack();
        }
    };

    public ElasticPanel()
    {
        prodCombo = new JComboBox[1];
        counter = 1;
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Elastic Panel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();

        basePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

        prodCombo[counter - 1] = new JComboBox(data);
        prodCombo[counter - 1].setActionCommand("" + (counter - 1));
        prodCombo[counter - 1].addActionListener(comboAction);

        basePanel.add(prodCombo[counter - 1]);
        contentPane.add(basePanel);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ElasticPanel().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Latest Update : **

More insight by adding more components and placing the elastic panel at some other location, and not on top of content pane.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class VirtualViewGUI extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel rightPanel;
    private ElasticPanel elasticPanel;

    public VirtualViewGUI()
    {
        super("Virtual View");

        JMenuBar jmenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenu feel = new JMenu("Look & Feel");

        JMenu layOutMenu = new JMenu("ConfigureCells");
        JMenuItem add_files = new JMenuItem("Select Directory.."); 
        JMenuItem minCellSize = new JMenuItem("height 260 X  width 260"); 
        JMenuItem moderateCellSize = new JMenuItem("height 320 X  width 320"); 
        JMenuItem maxCellSize = new JMenuItem("height 360 X  width 360"); 
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem help = new JMenuItem("Help Content");

        fileMenu.add(add_files);
        fileMenu.add(exit);
        layOutMenu.add(minCellSize);
        layOutMenu.add(moderateCellSize);
        layOutMenu.add(maxCellSize);
        helpMenu.add(help);

        jmenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        jmenuBar.add(layOutMenu);
        jmenuBar.add(helpMenu);

        ImageIcon myImage = null;
        try
        {
            myImage = new ImageIcon(
                new URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/" + 
                        "gaganisonline/images/swing/" + 
                        "stackoverflow/cow-cartoon.jpg"));
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException mue)    
        {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel icon = new JLabel(myImage);
        icon.setIcon(myImage);
        setJMenuBar(jmenuBar); 

        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        elasticPanel = new ElasticPanel(this);
        rightPanel.add(elasticPanel);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.add(icon, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);    
        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("File Separator is : " + System.getProperty("file.separator"));
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new VirtualViewGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ElasticPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    /*
     * Array to hold the JComboBox
     * elements.
     */
    private JComboBox[] prodCombo;  
    private JComboBox[] temp;
    /* 
     * Counter to keep track
     * of the number of JComboBox 
     * present.
     */
    private int counter;  
    /*
     * Data for each JComboBox
     */
    private String[] data = {
                                "None",
                                "Sub Category"
                            };

    private ActionListener comboAction =
            new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JComboBox cbox = (JComboBox) ae.getSource();
            String command = (String) ae.getActionCommand();
            int index = Integer.parseInt(command);
            String selection = (String) cbox.getSelectedItem();

            if (selection.equals("None"))
            {
                /*
                 * i = index + 1, because, we want to
                 * remove all JComboBox after this one.
                 */
                for (int i = (index + 1); i < prodCombo.length; i++)
                {
                    temp = new JComboBox[prodCombo.length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < prodCombo.length; j++)
                        temp[j] = prodCombo[j];
                    remove(prodCombo[i]);   
                }
                prodCombo = new JComboBox[index + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
                {                   
                    prodCombo[i] = temp[i];
                }
                counter = prodCombo.length;
                System.out.println("Item Removed\nCounter : " + counter);
            }
            else if (selection.equals("Sub Category"))
            {
                counter++;
                temp = new JComboBox[counter];
                for (int i = 0; i < prodCombo.length; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = prodCombo[i];
                }
                temp[counter - 1] = new JComboBox(data);
                temp[counter - 1].setActionCommand("" + (counter - 1));
                temp[counter - 1].addActionListener(this);
                prodCombo = new JComboBox[counter];
                for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                    prodCombo[i] = temp[i];
                add(prodCombo[counter - 1]);    
                System.out.println("Item Added\nCounter : " + counter);
            }

            //revalidate();
            //repaint();
            frame.pack();
        }
    };

    public ElasticPanel(JFrame frame)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
        prodCombo = new JComboBox[1];
        counter = 1;

        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

        prodCombo[counter - 1] = new JComboBox(data);
        prodCombo[counter - 1].setActionCommand("" + (counter - 1));
        prodCombo[counter - 1].addActionListener(comboAction);

        add(prodCombo[counter - 1]);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. That's exactly what I want. But the thing is in my case the elastic panel is not the only panel. It's a sub panel of the **basePanel**. Other panel's don't change. So do you say that I should still update the whole frame ? Actually previously I was trying to do something like that. But everyone said I should go for `cardLayout` and that's the best approach to this..

Comment: Never knew about the use of initializing `gridlayout` with zero rows (and columns), thanks! that comes very handy. Found [more info here](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Comment: I had tried to modify the code a bit more, for you to understand that your **elastic panel** needs to be inside another **JPanel** for it to actually work the way you wanted, without disturbing the Layout for other components. Please have a look at the updated answer :-) CardLayout IMHO, is meant for situations when you have more than one JPanel, and you need to swap views between them. Here in this case, you don't know how many JComboBoxes a user wants at the start, so CardLayout is really not a good approach in any sense.

Comment: Better would be if you have access to the latest [Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) THough if you would like to keep the frame size as is when new components are added, you can uncomment the lines at the end of `actionPerformed()` method and comment `frame.pack()`.

Comment: Thanks!! That's very nice of you. Appreciate your valuable effort. You solved my problem...

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you have 2 different panels and you switch between those 2 using a `CardLayout`. The problem with the `CardLayout` is that it takes the size of the largest panel.

So with the `CardLayout` you will not be able to shrink the size of the container, but you can avoid that the combobox is being stretched by wrapping your panels inside another panel with a `BorderLayout`, and putting the panel in the `BorderLayout.NORTH`